# Get same order data in js object

Tags: javascript, object

i have this object in js:

```
var Categories = {

    1: { 'id': 1, 'name': 'Uomo', 'has_child': 1 },
        5: { 'id': 4, 'name': 'Abbigliamento', 'has_child': 1 },
            10: { 'id': 9, 'name': 'Abiti' },
            15: { 'id': 10, 'name': 'Camicie' },
            20: { 'id': 11, 'name': 'Maglieria' },
            25: { 'id': 12, 'name': 'Pantaloni' },
            30: { 'id': 13, 'name': 'Topwear', 'end': 1 },
        35: { 'id': 5, 'name': 'Scarpe' },
        40: { 'id': 6, 'name': 'Accessori' },
        45: { 'id': 7, 'name': 'Sportivo' },
        50: { 'id': 8, 'name': 'Intimo', 'end': 1 },
    55: { 'id': 2, 'name': 'Donna', 'has_child': 1 },
        60: { 'id': 14, 'name': 'Abbigliamento', 'has_child': 1 },
            65: { 'id': 20, 'name': 'Abiti' },
            70: { 'id': 21, 'name': 'Camicie' },
            75: { 'id': 22, 'name': 'Maglieria' },
            80: { 'id': 23, 'name': 'Gonne' },
            85: { 'id': 24, 'name': 'Pantaloni' },
            90: { 'id': 25, 'name': 'Topwear', 'end': 1 },
        95: { 'id': 15, 'name': 'Scarpe' },
        100: { 'id': 16, 'name': 'Borse & Accessori' },
        105: { 'id': 17, 'name': 'Gioielli' },
        110: { 'id': 18, 'name': 'Sportivo' },
        115: { 'id': 19, 'name': 'Intimo', 'end': 1 },
    120: { 'id': 29, 'name': 'Bimbo', 'has_child': 1 },
        125: { 'id': 32, 'name': '0-24 mesi' },
        130: { 'id': 33, 'name': '3-8 anni' },
        135: { 'id': 34, 'name': '9-16 anni', 'end': 1 },
    140: { 'id': 3, 'name': 'Bimba', 'has_child': 1 },
        145: { 'id': 26, 'name': '0-24 mesi' },
        150: { 'id': 27, 'name': '3-8 anni' },
        155: { 'id': 28, 'name': '9-16 anni', 'end': 1 }

};
```

Now there is the difficult... I get a variable that we call category_id which contain the id of a category. Now with this ID I have to get the "name" of the related category.

Ex if category_id is 10 i have to get "Camicie", if is 7 i have to get "Sportivo".

I can't find the right code to do this...

Comment: @Pointy It's valid for an object literal (eg. `x = {1: 2}`), just not JSON.

Comment: It may not be valid JSON, but it is a valid JS object.

Comment: whoa `mind == blown` learn something every day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the keys and check the properties:

```
function findNameFromId(id) {
    for (var key in Categories) {
        if (Categories[key].id == id) {
            return Categories[key].name;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call this:

```
var name = findNameFromId("10"); //returns Camicie
```